# How to Pass Data from View Controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, viewcontroller

I want to pass a latitude data and longitude data to another controller called DestinationViewController. DestinationViewController contains a map view, so as user transitions to a new view, they will see a flyover map based on the location(latitude and longitude) data in the first view.

Now there is a few problems which I will explain along the way.

**FIRST VIEW**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class SliderViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
   private var latitude : [Double]!
   private var longtitude : [Double]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sliderSlides(self)

    }

  @IBAction func sliderSlides(sender: AnyObject) {

        let userChoice = Double(self.slider.value)

var realLatlong = [double]()
        if userChoice == 1 {
            realLatlong = [40.7484405, -73.9856644]
        }  else if possibility == 2 {
            realLatlong = [42.7484405, -4.9856644]
        } else {
            realLatlong = [50.7484405, -7.9856644]

        }


    latitude = [realLatlong[0]]
    longitude = [realLatlong[1]]
```

> NO error now, completely fine

```
}

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "sendLocationdata") {
            var destination: DestinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            as! DestinationViewController
```

> SIGABART

```
           destination.latitude = latitude
            destination.longtitude = longitude


        }
    }
```

}

**DestinationViewController**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class DestinationViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var latitude : Float!
    var longtitude : Float!
    let distance: CLLocationDistance = 700
    let pitch: CGFloat = 65
    let heading = 90.0
    var camera = MKMapCamera()
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!



    @IBOutlet var flyoverView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                        longitude: longitude)
```

> No error at all

```
        flyoverView.mapType = .SatelliteFlyover

        camera =  MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate,
                              fromDistance: distance,
                              pitch: 0,
                              heading: 0)
        self.flyoverView.camera = camera

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let pitchedCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate, fromDistance: distance, pitch: pitch, heading: 0)
        let rotatedCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate, fromDistance: distance, pitch: pitch, heading: 180)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: {
            self.flyoverView.camera = pitchedCamera

            }, completion: {
                (Completed: Bool) -> Void in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(25.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
                    self.flyoverView.camera = rotatedCamera
                    }, completion: nil)

        })

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Please help me. Leave a comment if you need more information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first error, latitude and longitude are variables in the scope of the sliderSlides function, meaning they exist only within that function. This is why you can't access them from your prepareForSegue. Make them class functions so that they exist in the scope of the class by declaring them outside of any function (I would suggest under your IBOutlet).

It should be like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

private var latitude:Double!
private var longitude:Double!
```

Then when you set them, instead of creating a new variable with let, just change the existing class variable:

```
latitude = realLatlong[0]
```

You should be able to access them now in your prepareForSegue.

Note also: Either give them an initial value like so:

```
private var latitude:Double = 0.0 //Or some default number
```

or check whether it is nil in prepareForSegue, because currently they will only get set if the sliderSlides function gets called.

For your second error:

You can't use your instance variables(latitude and longitude) to define another instance variable (coordinate). You should declare coordinate as a class variable, but not set its value until the view is loaded.

Replace:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                        longitude: longitude)
```

with:

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
```

and then in your viewDidLoad add:

```
coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                    longitude: longitude)
```

If you really don't want to initialise the coordinate in the viewDidLoad you can also do:

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    get {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                    longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

However I would highly suggest against this as you will be creating a new CLLocationCoordinate2D variable every time you call coordinate. Note also that this will update the coordinate value (in future use) whenever you change latitude and longitude

Also note: latitude and longitude shouldn't be of type Int (as you are requiring the use of the decimal points)

UPDATE:

Addressing your latest code update here because it is easier than in the comments:

In your SliderViewController change:

```
private var latitude : [Double]!
private var longtitude : [Double]!
```

to

```
private var latitude : Double!
private var longtitude : Double!
```

Because latitude and longitude are single variables, not arrays.

In the sliderSlides function change:

```
latitude = [realLatlong[0]]
longitude = [realLatlong[1]]
```

to

```
latitude = realLatlong[0]
longitude = realLatlong[1]
```

Because again, they are single values, not arrays.

Then in your DestinationViewController, change:

```
var latitude : Float!
var longtitude : Float!
```

to

```
var latitude : Double!
var longtitude : Double!
```

Because we need Double values, not Float values

Comment: I did what you have suggested, I got two errors, see my new edit.

Comment: Change longitude and latitude from Floats to Doubles. Then when you're setting longitude and latitude in sliderSlides you are making them arrays instead of just single values. I have updated my answer

Comment: Is there anyway to get slider value outside of @IBAction func?

Comment: Your update corrects most of my errors. There's only one more left, cannot convert value of type [Double] to expected argument type"CLLocationDegrees"(aka double) at the DestinationViewController. Maybe I misunderstand you, because I change all my type to arrays for example var latitude : [Double]!

Comment: Instead of types being [Double] (for latitude and long), they should just be Double. [Double] indicates that the type is an array of Double values, when in actuality you are only wanting one Double value

Comment: yeah because I change my type to double, now my second view controller has an error which I wrote earlier, how do I fix that?

Comment: Did you change latitude and longitude to Double in both view controllers? Can you please update your code in your question to show what it looks like now

Comment: I run the app, it crashes. On the line as! DestinationViewController, it said threat 1 Sigabart

Comment: I believe you should open a new question for this as it no longer fits the original question. When you do make sure you add information about how and when you are performing the segue (Programatically/through the storyboard). Also any information shown in the logs that might be helpful

Comment: Thank you. I posted my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982076/app-crashes-at-segue-breakpoint-occurs-at-prepareforsegue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is, you're setting the latitude and longitude to Int. 
Try changing the data type to Float, or something other data type like Double:

```
var latitude : Float!
var longtitude : Float!
```